# Semantic Mediawiki: trying to query subobjects

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I've [page](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/index.php?title=Tutti_gli_articoli_di_Marco_Crepaldi) with a long list of subojects. The [properties](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Speciale:Esplora/:Tutti-20gli-20articoli-20di-20Marco-20Crepaldi) are correctly visibile. I've [successfully queried that list from the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74531164/semantic-mediawiki-writing-a-query-that-returns-all-the-suboject-defined-in-a-p) and not I'm trying from [another page](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/index.php?title=Articoli_di_Marco_Crepaldi_sui_femminicidi):

I've magaed to point to the page, to filter for the tag, but it doesn't work as expected: it returns many tags (while it should return only one), it returns no title and 1 url.

```
{{#ask: [[-Has subobject::Tutti gli articoli di Marco Crepaldi]] [[Tags::femminicidi]]
|?tags
|?title
|?url
| mainlabel=-
}}
```

Comment: The only subobject at the page [Tutti gli articoli di Marco Crepaldi][1] has no tag *Feminicidi*, so, the query in your question cannot return any results.


  [1]: https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Speciale:Esplora/:Tutti-20gli-20articoli-20di-20Marco-20Crepaldi-23-5F97392b224fb27ee7de43694808c0eeb5

Comment: you messed with SemanticLink template I guess, your "long list of subobjects" has vanished.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin , IRA1777 may it be related to this change? https://www.tematichedigenere.com/index.php?title=Template:SemanticLink&type=revision&diff=28694&oldid=28517&diffmode=source

Comment: @IRA1777 I've fixed the long list of subobjects but the query for a single tag still doesn't work as I expected

Comment: Looks good to me, what did you expect ?

Comment: @IRA1777 I realized I had mispelled the tag in all the subobject except one xD!!! not it works!